# Unable to resolve Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string

Tags: jquery

Initially i am building Inner components  and then adding them to the top layer .

But i am getting

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string

This is my whole code

Initially i am bulding up a toppingcart then i am adding them to the toplevelcart (Every toplevelcart contains the same toppingcart )

```
for (var i = 0; i < toppingres[0].toppings.length; i++){
  toppingcart += '<section class="secclass" ><i id="topping-close"></i>'
  toppingcart += '<a  name="'+toppingres[0].toppings[i]+'" href="#">'+toppingres[0].toppings[i]+'</a>';
  toppingcart += '</section>';
  }


 for (var k = 0; k < quantity; k++){
  toplevelcart += '<section class="secclass"><h6 class="tdHeading">'+name+ k'</h6><i id="topping-close"></i>'
  toplevelcart += toppingcart;  // here i guess the problem is 
  toplevelcart += '</section>';
  }
```

Comment: It is the 'k' that is right here `g">'+name+ k'<`

Comment: @JayBlanchard yeah well spotted.

Comment: How can i make it appear name and both k dynamically ??

Comment: @PreethiJain concatenate it with `+` `g">'+name+ k +'<`

Comment: Use  this `g">'+name+k+'<`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is a simple typo:

```
for (var k = 0; k < quantity; k++){
  toplevelcart += '<section class="secclass"><h6 class="tdHeading">'+name+ k+'</h6><i id="topping-close"></i>'
  toplevelcart += toppingcart;  // here i guess the problem is ------------^
  toplevelcart += '</section>';
}
```